# Merge tags [apache-superset] and [superset]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[apache-superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-superset) appears to be an exact duplicate of [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superset). Tag descriptions are identical and posts are often tagged with both. Should they be merged or synonymized?

Should we retag all Apache-related [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superset) questions as [apache-superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-superset), and clean up the rest of the questions?

Answer (score 11):

As the term "superset" has a distinct meaning in set theory, I think that having it apply specifically to Apache Superset, when we have a more descriptive tag already available, can be misleading.

There are a few questions tagged [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superset) that do not relate to Apache Superset. Here are a few examples:

- Algorithm: [need an algorithm for collapsing netblock ranges into lists of superset ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149577/need-an-algorithm-for-collapsing-netblock-ranges-into-lists-of-superset-ranges)
- Druid: [superset 0.35.1 druid error: name 'PyDruid' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289314/superset-0-35-1-druid-error-name-pydruid-is-not-defined)
- Airbnb: [How to make changes in Airbnb Superset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444174/how-to-make-changes-in-airbnb-superset)

There are also many questions with both tags (over half the [apache-superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-superset), and over 60% of the [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superset) questions).

So my proposal is to retag all of the Apache related [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superset) questions as [apache-superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-superset), then either burn `superset`, or retarget the tag for one of the other meanings for "superset" (with appropriate wiki edits).

Comment: The second and third examples *are* Apache Superset questions. Second one involves an Apache Superset installation. In the third one, Airbnb Superset is the previous name of Apache Superset.

Comment: I think that this answer only shows evidence that a [superset] tag shouldn't exist.